# Wordpress plugin development. Include files

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am building a contact form plugin. In my main php file which is in the root of my plugin folder is trying to include a php file from public folder like this.

```
include '.\public\mpp_submitpost.php';
```

I tried everyway I know how and cannot get these 2 files to find each other. So I am new to wordpress and it has me thinking there is something else going on here that is caused by wordpress. Can someone explain to me why the way I tried will not work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'TheFileYouWantToImport.php' );
```

it's what you need.